# Get multiple SVG file contents using javascript/ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

I have multiple SVG files that I want to load asynchronously. I've written the following function that I can call:

```
function getSVG(fileName){
  getSVG = new XMLHttpRequest();
  getSVG.open('GET','assets/svg/'+fileName+'.svg',false);
  getSVG.send();
  return getSVG.responseXML.documentElement;
}
```

Now I can load the contents like so:

```
var baseSVG = getSVG('base');
document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(baseSVG);
```

That works great, but when I try to call it a second time it doesn't work. For example:

```
var midSVG = getSVG('mid');
document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(midSVG);
```

This time I get the following error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'getSVG' of object [object object] is not a function
```

I'm no great expert with javascript and ajax so not sure what this is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getSVG(fileName){       // <- create a function in the global namespace called getSVG
  var getSVG = new XMLHttpRequest(); // <- overwrite that function with a new XMLHttpRequest object
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah yes the var before the getSVG variable declaration? That seems to work now. Did you forget to put it in your answer though?

Comment: I had left it out on purpose so that the comment would makes sense, but as long as you understand that `var` is the culprit, the edit is fine with me